# Opera don't show body background

Tags: html, css, opera

I have a problem with Opera, it don't show de body background!

this is the css:

```
body{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#a6a6a6;
    font-size:smaller;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

This is the url of site: http://abs.marcmorales.es/index.php?s=2&i=1

What can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Regards!

Comment: Not sure why, but removing the `overflow-x:hidden;` rule makes the body expand.

Comment: I removed overflow-x:hidden; and the problem persist, do you see the background? Thanks

Comment: I do when I remove it with Dragonfly. My advice is to write a test file and remove stuff until you find out what causes the issue. Additionally, you should validate your HTML and CSS as part of your workflow: you have many validation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying it to your html selector (worked for me in Dragonfly).

```
html{background-color:#000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the body color in the body tag. Maybe then it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#a6a6a6;
    font-size:smaller;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```